# Laravel - How do you pass a variable through a signed URL?

Tags: php, laravel, email, routes

I'm trying to write my reset password code, and I cannot figure out how to pass the supplied email through a signed url, so that the corresponding view knows securely which email has been validated, and can change the password of the corresponding account. I just get invalid signature if I try and alter the URL and rightfully so, but how else can I pass this variable to the view using a signed url?

Emailed link:

```
<h1>Reset  Password</h1>
<h2>{{ $email }}</h2>
<a href="{{ $url }}">RESET</a>
```

Mailable class:

```
  */
    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->email = $data;
    }

    public function build()
    {
        $url = URL::temporarySignedRoute(
         'show.reset.form', now()->addMinutes(100)
        );
        return $this->from('support@xxxx.com')
                    ->view('auth.mail.resetLink')->with([
                        'url' => $url,
                        'email' => $this->email
                    ]);
    }
```

Trying to add variables to the url results in an error: Unsupported operand types

```
 $url = URL::temporarySignedRoute(
         'show.reset.form', ['email'=>$this->email], now()->addMinutes(100)
        );
```

Any help would be fantastic! Thankyou :)

Comment: from the url? isn't `Request` object handle those things? like `$request->email` like accessing members

Comment: or i think even the helper `request()` will work too

Comment: Okay I understand what youre saying, how can I add variables to the signed url?

Comment: Where I make the url, if I pass variables in an array ['x'=>$y] etc. it errors "unsupported operand types"

Comment: in the method you used above, i think you got the second and third argument switched, the duration is the second argument, the variables needed to be added for the third

Comment: it says it in here https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/urls#signed-urls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may do like this.

```
    $url = URL::temporarySignedRoute(
       'show.reset.form', now()->addMinutes(100), [
          'email' => $this->email 
       ]
    );
```